# Error in rotation_difference?

Tags: python, scripting, error

Hi StackExchange users !

I'm trying to get the rotation between two vectors, but I think I get a wrong answer using mathutils.rotation_difference :

With :

```
vec_1 = Vector((0.0,1.0,0.0))
vec_2 = Vector((0.0, -1.0, 0.0))
[math.degrees(o) for o in vec_1.rotation_difference(vec_2 ).to_euler()]
```

I get :

```
[179.999991348578, -89.99998884409983, 0.0]
```

But this is incorrect. The correct answer should be (?) :

```
[179.999991348578, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Anyone has any idea why I'm getting this answer ? Am I using this correctly ?
Thx, T.

Comment: IMO the rotation difference is correct, your expectation is `R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(180), 3, 'X')` ie rotating about the x axis. Both `R' and the matrix from vector rotational difference   when multiplied by (0, 1, 0) will return (0, -1, 0)  Since the z component is 0.  Try this in UI with cube, select transform orientation local  and crunch the two rotations above in. The difference is local x up and down.

Comment: @batFINGER thx, I just get from your answer that I got an issue between local and global conversions of rotations, but still no clue how to manage that. Any idea ?

Comment: Just mentioned the local axes as a way to visualize the two rotations  in question above, both result in  y axis flipped.  The rotation difference is a quaternion (easier said than explained) that when applied as a rotation on vector a produces vector b, not necessarily by rotating about x axis.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning too that two parallel vectors is a side case. If they were not ||'lel then the cross product would be the axis of rotation. For this case can choose any arbitrary point that is not on y axis, and the vector from that point to closest point on line  can be used as the axis of revolution.  Not sure how blender chooses this point, would need to look into mathutils source code.

Comment: I just get it :) Yes the rotation difference is correct, and I verified it ! Thx again @batFINGER